# How can I install nodejs on the "amazonlinux:2023" docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get a NodeJS + Express + Sqlite3 app to run as an AWS Lambda.

To get a useable GLIBC I'm resorting to the amazonlinux:2023 candidate image... which has GLIBC_2.33 but no NodeJS. (I got to this after a long Yak shave trying to build GLIBC, messing with node-pre-gyp etc. etc. etc.)

Of course amazonlinux:2023 gives the "You don't appear to be running a supported version of Enterprise Linux." error. Is there some other way to install some modern-ish version of NodeJS?

My end goal is an AWS Lambda that will run NodeJS and the sqlite3 library.

Comment: Why would you need glibc? Does aws use some creative flavour of sqlite3 that doesn't have a precompiled binary? Also, a casual google shows multiple tutorials on how to do this, did none of those work? If so, where did you actually get stuck? (i.e. what is the _specific_ problem you're trying to solve in the process of setting this up, rather than merely the general "wanting to set this up"?)

Comment: AWS node images don't ship with sqlite3, and I'm on a Mac ... so zipping doesn't seem to work (even with node-pre-gyp), and the images all seem to die on the "Error: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-glibc-arm64/node_sqlite3.node)" error.

Comment: Also, "the specific problem" is right there at the top: "I'm trying to get a NodeJS + Express + Sqlite3 app to run as an AWS Lambda." It's a really simple 'hit an end-point, search a small static db, return the results as JSON' app.

Answer (score 0):

With the amazon linux 2023 image you can just use `dnf` to install `nodejs`.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:2023

RUN dnf install -y nodejs
```